# Start a Powershell Script from Powershell, Cancel it and return to Powershell

Tags: powershell

We have `someScript.ps1` which should do some stuff then call `tail.ps1` (which tails a logfile). When the user see's a certain event in the logfile (e.g. that the service has stopped) they should be able to cancel `tail.ps1` with Ctrl+C and return to the flow of `someScript.ps1`.

I guess this is possible using the windows `start` command to call a .bat file which calls the powershell script but wondered if there's a way to just call `tail.ps1` from PS without the need for a .bat.

Note: Using `& .\tail.ps1` does not work as desired. Ctrl+C cancels both scripts i.e. also `someScript.ps1`. We are using `Get-Content -Wait` to tail.

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you the logic to set off.

First, you run your **somescript.ps1** and inside that you call the **tail.ps1** as job.

```
start-job -filepath c:\scripts\tail.ps1
```

Now you can stop the job by using **Stop-Job** based on certain conditions as you have mentioned(e.g., the service has stopped).

Then you can receive the output of the job by using **Receive-Job** and even you can wait for the job to complete by using **Wait-Job**

Based on your condition you can use a *do-While* and you can receive the job or you can stop the job as per your requirement.

So finally,it will have the control back to the **somescript.ps1** only.

For further reference on job please go through the link or you can ask here.

Below link has complete explanation with screenshots :

[Dealing with PS Jobs](http://www.howtogeek.com/138856/geek-school-learn-how-to-use-jobs-in-powershell/)

Hope this logic helps you.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want a parallel (asynchronous) process but a serial (synchronous) process. The main process should only continue when this (tail.ps1) is closed.

Comment: @Marc:  Thats what, if you are waiting for the job to complete using wait-job then it won't be a parallel process. So you can use it for your purpose.

Comment: OK, I understand but my main script is not able to stop the tail. The user must decide and press something to end it (e.g. Ctrl+C to cancel it). In our case the NT service stops before the actual Java process is done stopping.

Comment: You can use `Stop-Job` for stopping the job which triggers the start-job for the **tail.ps1**

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer, please accept it also.